# How to delete a registry root through C#

Tags: c#, registry, directory

I've been looking for days for an answer but the only answers I found were to delete registry keys or values.

I apologize if the answer exists but I have tried very hard to find the answer as to not ask a question that has already been answered.

Basically what I need is a way to delete a WHOLE registry folder through C# from the LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE path. EG: LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABC , deleting the whole ABC "folder".

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(@"Software\ABC");
```

Be wary:  LOCAL_MACHINE is protected, and without Admin privileges, this is likely to fail.

I wonder if your difficulty in searching is simply terminology.  Everything that is not a value is a key.  In your words, "folder" equals key.  It just a nested structure with values along the way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it has not solved my problem but you were right by saying that I was using the same terminology. Since the above did not work I was assuming that a "registry folder" was not key and tried to look for something different.

PS: The only problem I have now is that the program is stating that the key does not exist although i'm pretty sure it is there.

Comment: Pretty sure?  Can you see it using the RegEdit tool?  And if so, then it's probably exposure...or lack thereof due to permissions.  In other words, you seeing it using RegEdit does not mean your code will.

Comment: That's probably it, thanks a lot for your help, your answer clarified a lot. I'll keep looking in existing question now that I know what I need to look for, thanks to you :))